# Does anyone know where storyboard option is for xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

xcode screenshot

[image: xcode screenshot]

How can I create a project with storyboard? I don't see the interface dropdown. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to create Multiplatform app:

[image]

In this case SwiftUI is used by default but you can add storyboards to your app manually later.

If you don't want to create a multiplatform app just select needed platform: iOS, macOS etc. and you can switch Interface to Storyboard:

[image]